# Flutter app keeps stoping when i'm trying to extarct text from image using google_ml_vision: ^0.0.7

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to extract Arabic text from an image using  google_ml_vision: ^0.0.7,
I wrote the function below, but when I call it the app crashed(its crashed in this point await textRecognizer.processImage(visionImage))  without providing any logs
the image path is correct but it still didn't work

```
  Future _extarctArabicTexFromImage() async {
    try {
      // final File imageFile = File(imgPath);

      final GoogleVisionImage visionImage =
          GoogleVisionImage.fromFilePath(imgPath);

      final TextRecognizer textRecognizer =
          GoogleVision.instance.textRecognizer();
      late VisionText visionText;
      try {
        visionText = await textRecognizer.processImage(visionImage);

      } catch (e) {
        print(e.toString());
      }
      // String  text = visionText.text;
      for (var block in visionText.blocks) {
        final List<RecognizedLanguage> languages = block.recognizedLanguages;

        for (var line in block.lines) {
          for (var textElement in line.elements) {
            txt = txt + " " + textElement.text.toString();
          }

          txt = txt + '\n';
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

Comment: I reccommend using google_ml_kit(https://pub.dev/packages/google_ml_kit) .

Comment: I use it but it still doesn't support the Arabic language